# Compiling SASS in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, compilation, sass

I'm planning to use SASS in making a website instead of CSS. I'm trying to compile a SASS file to CSS. Should I use an application to do so? Or should I use just command prompt?

Comment: do you have a Ruby or NodeJs installed on your PC?

Comment: I have a ruby installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Ruby then install gem SASS. Just type into command line `gem install sass`.

> Once Sass is installed, you can run `sass input.scss output.css` from your terminal. You can watch either individual files or entire directories. In addition, you can watch folders or directories with the --watch flag. An example of running Sass while watching an entire directory is the following:
>   `sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets`